# 'tuple' object has no attribute 'get'

Tags: python, django

I am new to Django framework and I am trying to perform the Django authentication views but i keep on getting this error

```
C:\Users\Harsley\bookmarks>python manage.py runserver
Performing system checks...

System check identified no issues (0 silenced).
March 21, 2017 - 21:11:56
Django version 1.10.6, using settings 'bookmarks.settings'
Starting development server at http://127.0.0.1:8000/
Quit the server with CTRL-BREAK.
Internal Server Error: /
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Harsley\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 42, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "C:\Users\Harsley\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django\utils\deprecation.py", line 138, in __call__
    response = self.process_response(request, response)
  File "C:\Users\Harsley\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django\middleware\clickjacking.py", line 32, in process_response
    if response.get('X-Frame-Options') is not None:
AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'get'
[21/Mar/2017 21:11:58] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 500 57044
```

This is my url.py file

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from django.contrib.auth import views as auth_views
from . import views
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^login$', auth_views.login, name='login'),
    url(r'^logout$', auth_views.logout, name='logout'),
    url(r'^logout_then_login$', auth_views.logout_then_login, `name='logout_then_login'),`
    url(r'^$', views.dashboard, name='dashboard'),
]
```

Here is my views

```
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
@login_required()
def dashboard(request):
    return (request, 'dashboard.html', {'section': 'dashboard'})
```

Comment: Show, please, your `views.dashboard` views

Comment: I have added it

Comment: Paste the complete error Traceback. What you've posted hardly tells anything.

Comment: that's the complete Traceback error i am getting

Answer (score 4):

This is wrong:

```
return (request, 'dashboard.html', {'section': 'dashboard'})
```

You are returning a `tuple` where you have to return a [Response](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/http/views/#a-simple-view).

Instead of directly returning a response you can use the [`render`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/http/shortcuts/#example)-shortcut:

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required

@login_required()
def dashboard(request):
    return render(request, 'dashboard.html', {'section': 'dashboard'})
```